# Initialise a private class field with values returned by async function

Tags: flutter, asynchronous

I have this simple component.

It has a private class field called `_myStorage` that I need to initialise calling the async function `preload`.

So, initially I set to it an empty String, and then in the `initState` I call `preload` that reassign the new value to `_myStorage` and do a `setState`.

The problem is that it seems not to work because when I print `_myStorage` it is an empty String instead of `Lorem ipsum`.

Why? How can I solve?

I just need to initialise `_myStorage` with the values computed in `preload` function.

```dart
class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PageState createState() => _PageState();
}

class _PageState extends State<Page> {
  MyStorage _myStorage = MyStorage(
    myValue: '',
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    preload();
  }

  void preload() async {
    MyStorage filledMyStorage;
    String? myValue = await getPrefsString('myValue');
    print('myValue: $myValue'); // 'Lorem ipsum'

    filledMyStorage = MyStorage(
      myValue: myValue ?? '',
    );

    setState(() {
      _myStorage = filledMyStorage;
    });
    print('_myStorage: $_myStorage'); // ''
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('_myStorage: $_myStorage'); // ''
}


Future<String?> getPrefsString(String key) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String? value = prefs.getString(key);
  return value;
}
```

and `MyStorage` class is this:

```dart
class MyStorage {
  String myValue;

  MyStorage({
    required this.myValue
  });

  Map toJson() => {
    'myValue': myValue
  };

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '(myValue: $myValue)';
  }
}
```

Comment: what if you print `${_myStorage.myValue}`? maybe it is the right value but toString() of a `MyStorage` doesn't reflect its value

Comment: @IvoBeckers Thank you for the reply, I tried but it's the same: empty string

Comment: Can you maybe share the code of `MyStorage`? I can't see anything wrong here, so maybe there is something wrong

Comment: @IvoBeckers Of course, I edited my main message

Comment: Looks fine too. I don't know what's wrong, wish I could help you. Hopefully someone else has an idea